# Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder android.system.keystore2.IKeystoreService.asBinder()' on a null object using MasterKey

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried `MasterKey` since `MasterKeys` is depricated and below is the stacktrace.

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.a.b.c: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder android.system.keystore2.IKeystoreService.asBinder()' on a null object reference
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6790)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2134)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7898)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder android.system.keystore2.IKeystoreService.asBinder()' on a null object reference
  at android.security.KeyStore2.getService (KeyStore2.java:144)
  at android.security.KeyStore2.handleRemoteExceptionWithRetry (KeyStore2.java:105)
  at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyEntry (KeyStore2.java:252)
  at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.getKeyMetadata (AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:156)
  at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineContainsAlias (AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:1007)
  at java.security.KeyStore.containsAlias (KeyStore.java:1314)
  at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKeys.keyExists (MasterKeys.java:154)
  at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKeys.getOrCreate (MasterKeys.java:96)
  at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKey$Builder.buildOnM (MasterKey.java:357)
  at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKey$Builder.build (MasterKey.java:314)
  at com.a.b.c.d.EncryptedSharedPrefs.init (EncryptedSharedPrefs.kt:39)
```

My function looks like this.

```
    spec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS ,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
        )
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .setKeySize(MasterKey.DEFAULT_AES_GCM_MASTER_KEY_SIZE)
            .build()

        masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(context)
            .setKeyGenParameterSpec(spec)
            .build()

        encryptedSharedPref = EncryptedSharedPreferences
            .create(
                context,
                context.packageName + ".secure",
                masterKey,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
            )
```

Target SDK is 31. Thanks!